# Chaining MySQL commands Vs. Raw queries

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have been building a lot of website in the past using my own cms/framework and I have developed a simple way of executing queries. Recently I have started playing with other frameworks such as code igniter. They offer raw query imputs such as…

```
$this->db->query(“SELECT * FROM news WHERE newsId=1;”);
```

But they also offer chaining of MySQL command via PHP methods.

```
$this->db->select("*")->from("news")->where("newsId=?");
```

The question is; what is the main difference and of benefits of each option.

I know the latter options prevents MySQL injection but to be honest you can do exactly the same from using `$this->db->escape()`.

So in the end from what I can see the latter option only serves to make you use more letters on your keyboard, this you would think would slow you down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most recent php framework developers are uses AR(active record)/DAO(database access object) Pattern. Because it's really faster then raw query. Nowadays AR technique originally built from PDO(php data object).

**why active record is really faseter?**

its true query writing is the best habit for a developer. But some problem make it tough

**1.** When we write insert and update large query, sometime it's hard to match every row value.. but AR make it easy. you just add array first and then execute easily.
 
**2.** Doesn't matter what DB you use.
**3.** Sometimes it's really hard read or write query if it has many condition. But in AR you can cascade many object for 1 query.
**4.** AR save your time to repeating statement

Comment: DAOs aren't necessarily faster. On the contrary, there's a whole lot of code that translates the DAL interface into actual SQL queries, which is certainly *slower* than writing queries yourself. Also often a handcrafted query can be more efficient than something the DAL cobbled together itself based on templates and common cases.

Answer (score 2):

I think the implementation of activerecord in codeigniter is suitable for small and easy queries.
When you need complex queries with lots of joins, it is more clear to just write the query itself.

I don't think that an extra layer of abstraction will ever give you better performance, if you have a certain skill in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for CodeIgniter (what I've seen of it seems rather slung-together, frankly), but there are a few reasons such systems may be used:

- as part of an abstraction layer which supports different DBMS back-ends, where for instance `->offset(10)->limit(10)` would automatically generate the correct variant of `OFFSET`, `LIMIT`, and similar clauses for MySQL vs PostgreSQL etc
- as part of an "ORM" system, where the result of the query is automatically mapped into Model objects of an appropriate class based on the tables and columns being queried
- to abstract away from the exact names of tables and columns for backwards-compatibility, or installation requirements (e.g. the table "news" might actually be called "app1_news" in a particular install to avoid colliding with another application)
- to handle parameterised queries, as in your example; although largely unrelated to this kind of abstraction, they provide more than just escaping, as the DBMS (MySQL or whatever is in use) knows which parts of the query are fixed and which are variable, which can be useful for performance as well as security